# Why is sum of roots of quadratic equation power an integer coefficients of the expansion $-f'(x)/f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, quadratics

My high school teacher taught me a easy way to calculate the

$$\sum\frac{1}{a^n}\qquad n\in \mathbb{Z}$$ where $a$ is the roots of a quadratic equation in the form  $f(x)=x^2+ ax +b$.

He told me to find the derivative of $f(x)$
$f'(x) = 2x + a$.

The find $-f'(x)/f(x)$ which is going to be an infinite series.

Suppose $\frac{-f'(x)}{f(x)} = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3.....$

He stated that:

$\sum\frac{1}{a^0}= a_0$

$\sum\frac{1}{a^1}= a_1$

$\sum\frac{1}{a^2}= a_2$
And so on...

My doubt is why is this true? I wanted a proof.

PS: I hope my MathJax formatting is correct. I am new to this community so I would like recommendations from members.

Comment: Are you sure of the formulæ? It is trivially false for $f(x)=x^2-1$.

Comment: Express the root in terms of your coefficient and it is a geometric series

Comment: Or use $ P'/P = \sum_i \dfrac{\alpha_i} {(x-a_i)} $ for a polynom $P$ where $\alpha_i$ is the multiplicity of the root $a_i$ of P.

Comment: @Bernard It has worked for $x^2 -5x + 6$ and other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be a monic polynomial of degree $d$ with all roots $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_d$ simple. In other words, $$ f(x)=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\cdots (x-\alpha_d)=\prod_{k=1}^d(x-\alpha_k).$$
Then $$\ln f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^d\ln(z-\alpha_k) $$
and with $g(z):=-\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$, we observe
$$ -g(z)=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\ln f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^d\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\ln(z-\alpha_k)=\sum_{k=1}^d\frac1{z-\alpha_k}.$$
Now use the geometric series
$$\frac1{\alpha_k-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_k^{n+1}z^n$$ 
so that by comparing coefficients of equal powers of $z$ in the power series, we conclude $$a_n= \sum_{k=1}^ d\alpha_k^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have understood the proof except for the part where $f'(z)/f(z)$ is replaced by $d(ln(z)/dz$. Why is that?